# 301 redirect addon domain improperly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with url `http://abc.com/myfolder/`, now i add a addon domain "`xyz.com`" in cpanel and point it to `myfolder`. The addon domain is working successfully. `xyz.com` is showing what `http://abc.com/myfolder/` showing. However `http://abc.com/myfolder/` is already indexed in google, thus i want to do a 301 redirect from `http://abc.com/myfolder/` to `xyz.com`. I searched online and did something like below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myfolder/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but the redirect failed. showing "The page isn't redirecting properly". What can i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have first to check that the host is abc.com before applying the rule, otherwise, you end up applying the rule for both abc.com and xyz.com which result an infinite redirection loop.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.com$
RewriteRule ^myfolder/?(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```